# Force login and continue request on AccessDeniedException spring

Tags: java, spring-security, authorization, access-denied

Trying to create my own access handling logic via spring security. Some actions are controlled by custom logic. So: if the specific condition is satisfied - we allow user to do some action. If not - we should redirect hit to login page, force him to re-login and then continue action.

This is my custom access manager:

```
@Component("accessManager")
public class AccessManager
{
    public boolean hasAccess()
    {
        // Or true in some cases.
        return false;
    }
}
```

My spring config:

```
 <!-- HTTP security configurations -->
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/dataAccessFailure"/>
        <form-login login-processing-url="/resources/j_spring_security_check" login-page="/login" />
        <logout logout-url="/resources/j_spring_security_logout" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated() and @accessManager.hasAccess()" />
        <csrf disabled="true"/>
    </http>
```

Now it works like this: When I am trying to access requests like *"/**"* without being Authenticated, it redirects me to login page. 
Then I have to log in and after that I can continue processing request. 
But if the condition in my custom hasAccess() wethod is NOT satisfied, I can only see dataAccessFailure page. 
The main problem is that I need re-login behavior only in case of NO *hasAccess()* case (not for each AccessDeniedException). In cases like

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('MyAuth')")
```

I have to see dataAccessFailure page.
Thank you.

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean? `But is the condition in my custom hasAccess() wethod is NOT satisfied, I can only see dataAccessFailure page. The main problem is that I need re-login behavior only in case of NO hasAccess() case (not for each AccessDeniedException).` Your question is unclear

Comment: The reason is that you are only redirected to login page, if you are not logged in. If you are authenticated, but not authorized, you always redirected to your access denied page. That's the way Spring Security is implemented.

Comment: @Andrew Nepogoda typo, (is = if).

Comment: take a look a comment above. @dur 100% correct. P.s. Ты пытаешься использовать PreAuthorize не для тех целей ;)

Comment: @AndrewNepogoda User tries to perform a request like '"/**" (mentioned in intersept-urls). If AccessManager.hasAccess() method returns true, we allow him to do it. If not user is redirected to login page and after re-login he is checked again with AccessManager.hasAccess(). If it returns true, his previous request is continued.

Comment: Read the difference between authentication and authorization.